# Upload and download a file using FTP without ActiveX

Tags: vbscript, upload, ftp

I want VBScript to upload and download a file using FTP without using ActiveX program.

Notice please give me download code alone and upload code alone and must upload file not folder.

For example:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
path = "test.txt"

FTPUpload(path)

Sub FTPUpload(path)
  On Error Resume Next
  Const copyType = 16
  waitTime = 80000
  FTPUser = "user"
  FTPPass = "pass"
  FTPHost = "www.domain.com"
  FTPDir = "/htdocs/"
  strFTP = "ftp://" & FTPUser & ":" & FTPPass & "@" & FTPHost & FTPDir
  Set objFTP = oShell.NameSpace(strFTP)
  'objFTP.NewFolder "FTP Backup"    
  If objFSO.FileExists(path) Then
    Set objFile = objFSO.getFile(path)
    strParent = objFile.ParentFolder
    Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(strParent)
    Set objItem = objFolder.ParseName(objFile.Name)
    Wscript.Echo "Uploading file " & objItem.Name & " to " & strFTP
    objFTP.CopyHere objItem, copyType
  End If
  If objFSO.FolderExists(path) Then
    Set objFolder = oShell.NameSpace(path)
    Wscript.Echo "Uploading folder " & path & " to " & strFTP
    objFTP.CopyHere objFolder.Items, copyType
  End If
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Description
  End If
  WScript.Sleep waitTime
End Sub
```

Comment: the problem on the code it is take time to close it alone what ever is size of the file, i want the code to upload the file and close when finish it selve or give me another code it is upload file on ftp and close when finish

Comment: this code is for upload i want code to download file from ftp using vbscript without activex

Comment: Sorry, SO is not a "do my work for me" type of place. What have you tried so far, an what *specific* problem do you need help with?

Comment: i have question did you read the above comments ??